# Workplace riddle. Help find the location of the lost object

Tags: riddle

Help find the lost object, it is hidden in my workplace in this location:

> When turned off, my den is useless, but once turned on, it offers you
> a world of possibilities.
>
> My den is made of aluminum and other more precious metals. Despite >appearances, it does not serve anyone.

If I work in an IT company, where is the object?

The object doesn't matter really it can be an object the size of 4 inches by 4 inches by 4 inches. Finding the LOCATION is the point.

You can navigate through the office [here](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Nm%C3%A9dia+Solutions+Inc/@45.8688027,-72.472513,3a,75y,214h,88t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipN0PGJ6EfzwXZbo1912NICLdsPMaBIy8hqwW31K!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipN0PGJ6EfzwXZbo1912NICLdsPMaBIy8hqwW31K%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-2.9338646-ya214.5-ro0-fo100!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x4cc8113b59a3c2fb:0xd1311b5640e9ab1a!8m2!3d45.8688627!4d-72.4724023).

Comment: Is it a real object or can it be a virtual item?

Comment: it is a real object

Comment: A last question: Is google maps needed to solve this riddle? Or is it just for fun and athmosphere?

Comment: It is the real workplace. So it is somewhere in there

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you a receptionist?

Comment: No i'm not a receptionnist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After possibly familiarizing myself more with your office than my own house, here are my last few guesses:

> 3d printer/scanner

or

> Coffee machine (you put a cup in)

and lastly

> microwave (or anything else in the kitchen like a freezer or oven)

No real deduction here, these are simply the only 3 objects I could find that both fit something of 4  by 4 by 4 inches and actively do something with it. (e.g. a waste bin doesn't do anything)

Comment: I see zero explanation of why any one of these three might be correct. The OP has accepted so presumably understands some reasoning. How about some details for the rest of us?

Comment: It was no real deduction, just guessing. I'll add that to the post though. Request for OP to tell us the correct answer as I had 3 guesses and still don't know the correct one.

Comment: Bit broad of a riddle though still. Also don't understand what happened to the main post...

Answer (score 0):

A bit vague of a riddle...

Do you mean a

> USB stick? (or CD or whatever else goes into a pc (the den))

Comment: Well I said a key but it can be a place where a object the size of 4 inches by 4 inches by 4 inches can be placed

Answer (score 0):

Can it be

> Something like the Amazon Echo box that can control power, appliances etc.? 
>  When turned off the office space is not usable but when on, a world of Info is available.

Comment: No box from objects

Answer (score 0):

It is a

> CCTV camera's observing portion/capturing device (small iconoscope)

Comment: it is not finding THE object but the LOCATION of the object (the object can be anything small)